# R: Efficiently extract rows with different element in specified column by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to extract the specified rows according to `colC` which should include different elements by groud `by = list(colA, colB)`. Here is my code:

```
dt <- data.table(colA = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                 colB = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30), 
                 colC = c("A", "I", "A", "A", "A", "I", "A"))
dt
sg <- dt[, length(unique(colC)) != 1, by = list(colA, colB)]
sg

sg <- sg[sg[, V1]]
sg


> dt
    colA colB colC
1:    1   10    A
2:    1   10    I
3:    1   10    A
4:    2   20    A
5:    2   20    A
6:    3   30    I
7:    3   30    A

> sg
    colA colB    V1
1:    1   10  TRUE
2:    2   20 FALSE
3:    3   30  TRUE

> sg
   colA colB   V1
1:    1   10 TRUE
2:    3   30 TRUE
```

Here, the final `sg` is what I want, but when the number of samples are large, `length(unique(colC)) != 1` is slow.

Can you help work out how to speed up my operation or better method to finish what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `dt[, if(uniqueN(colC) != 1) TRUE, .(colA, colB)]` from V >= 1.9.5 [on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Thanks @David Arenburg. use your method, it spend ~207 seconds, use my method it spent ~445 sends. It is perfect!

Comment: David's suggestion is right on. But if you don't mind slightly more memory usage, `unique(dt)[, .N != 1L, by=.(colA, colB)][(V1)]` might be faster...

Comment: Thanks @Arun. Sure, your method is fatest. The same problem it just spent ~30 seconds.

Comment: Great! Maybe you can answer it yourself and accept it (so that the Q remains answered)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, @Arun gave the better answer. It is perfect! Thanks.

`sg <- unique(dt)[, .N != 1L, by=.(colA, colB)][(V1)]`